# How do I allow my program to perform something based on the type of user input?

Tags: java

I have created a 'car finance' calculator in Java however I want to make sure that not only the happy path is covered. When the user enters a string, the program quits because it's expecting an integer. Then I thought what if I set the input as a string and then convert it to an integer but I only want this conversion to happen IF the input is recognised as an integer... if that makes sense.

```
if(a.equalsIgnoreCase("Blue Car")) {
        System.out.println("This car is £9,000");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please type in your deposit amount."); 

        String value = "";
        int intValue;
        value = input.nextLine(); 
        try {
        intValue = Integer.valueOf(value);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Please print only numbers!");
        }           


        if(value < 9000) {
        System.out.println("The price of the car after your deposit is: " + (9000 - intValue)); 

        System.out.println("Please confirm the left over price after your deposit by typing it in.");
        int value1 = 0;
        value1 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("How long would you like the finance to be?"); 
        System.out.println("12 Months, 24 Months, 36 Months, 48 Months");
        System.out.println("Please type either 12, 24, 36 etc"); 
        int value2 = 0;
        value2 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("You will be paying " + value1 / value2 + " pounds a month!"); }
        else if(value.equalsIgnoreCase ("")){
            System.out.println("Please only enter numbers.");
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Great - you can pay the car in full!");
            chooseOption = true; 
        }
```

I tried using parseInt however I **only want parseInt to happen if a number is entered.**

I want my program to be able to recognise if the user input is an integer, then perform the if/else statement which does calculations with that integer and if the input is NOT an integer then I want a message to pop up saying 'Please make sure you enter numbers'.

**UPDATE**

I have added the method in which someone suggested in comments but I am unsure how to fit it in with the code I have as it's telling me still that value is not an integer and therefore I cannot use '<'.

Comment: You are doing `if(value < 9000) `, but `value` is your string, `intValue` is your integer. Please try not to change your question with edits. Edits are for clarification of your original question, not for asking follow-up questions. If you have a new question, ask a new question. You can link back to this one for context.

Comment: Sorry, no worries. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs of `java.lang.Integer`:

> **Throws:**
>   NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable integer.

So simply catch that exception, and you know the String didn't contain a parsable integer.

```
int result;
try {
    result = Integer.parseInt(value);
}
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // value was not valid, handle here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

You are on exactly the right path but you need to understand exceptions - when parseInt tries to Parse a value that isn't an integer it throws an exception. In Java we can catch and exception and deal with it (rather than letting it kill the run of the program).

For your case it looks like this:

```
try {
  int result = Integer.parseInt(value);           
  //Do your normal stuff as result is valid
}
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
   // Show your message "Please only enter numbers"  
}
//Code continues from here in either case
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [StringUtils.isNumeric](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNumeric-java.lang.CharSequence-) if you feel like adding a third party library.

If your use case is simple enough, I would probably do as follows:

```
int intValue;
String value = "";
value = input.nextLine(); 
try {
    intValue = Integer.valueOf(value);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("Please print only numbers!");
}
```

Comment: Just a minor note: `StringUtils.isNumeric` returns true also for strings that are not parsable by `Integer.parseInt`, if the value is out of range for a 32 bit integer.

Comment: Good to know. Indeed, there are better options than Integer.parseInt depending on the possible ranges for the input number (Long.parseLong, for instance).

Comment: Hi, I have updated my questions and included this method but also added a bit more of my code as I am unsure of how to fit this method in and for it to work with my if/else statements.

Comment: `Long.parseLong` can still fail if the value is out of range for 64 bit, so you need to catch `NumberFormatException` anyways. But a combination of `StringUtils.isNumeric` and catching the `NumberFormatException` can help create better error messages for a human user, e.g. differentiate between an input value that is an out of range integer ("Please enter a number between x and y") and one that is simply not an integer at all ("Please enter a number").